# Odata DataServiceQuery response object only has last value of of collection returned from the server

Tags: c#, wcf, odata

I have a Odata 2.0 server, that I have generated a DataService client for using the Visual Studio oData connected service wizard.  When I make a call to fetch an item the server is returning all 10 linked items for the ORDERITEM collection but the deserialize result has only one item in the collection and item in the collection is the last entity in the list returned by the server.

I noticed that the ORDERITEM class has an DataServiceKeyAttribute however its value is set to a field links the class to the parent.

```
[global::System.Data.Services.Common.DataServiceKeyAttribute("OrderNumber")]
public partial class OrderItem : global::System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
```

So, the OrderNumber is the same for all items returned by the server.

```
var bct = new ZZ_Entities( new Uri(server + "ZZ_SRV"));

        var query = bct.OrderSet.Expand(ogh => ogh.ORDERITEM)
            .Where( x=> x.OrderNumber == orderNumber).Select(oss => oss);

        DataServiceQuery<Order> osQquery = (DataServiceQuery<Order>)query;

        TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Order>> taskFactory = new TaskFactory<IEnumerable<Order>>();

        IEnumerable<OrderGetHeader> result = await taskFactory.FromAsync(
            osQquery.BeginExecute(null, null),
            iar => osQquery.EndExecute(iar));
```

Am I missing a setting or is there something I have to change with the generated class to make the deserialize process insert all items into the collection?

Comment: So what do you mean by "insert all items into the collection"? Your code seems to just be querying, not inserting records.

Comment: When I get a response from the server the collections have 1 item when they should have 10.

Comment: Do you have any equality members defined for the client classes? Like have you overrode `object.Equals` or the `==` operator?

Comment: When I first ran into the issue, I had nothing overloading object.Equals or the == operator.  As a step to see if items where incorrectly marked as identical, I did overload object.Equals but every call was comparing the same data. It seems the framework is inserting the same object into the collection.